# are bootstrap frameworks designed for handheld devices rather than conventional browsers

Tags: css, responsive-design, internet-explorer-8, media-queries, fluid-layout

We will still be relying on IE 8 and IE 9 in my company (too large to switch rapidly), so this stays. We have been trying to use bootstrap for the new internal site designs (with all the recommended quirks).

I noticed that the SB Admin v1 & v2 consistently break on these two browsers - both the official sites, and when we try to use these libraries locally. It still renders crazy, and code appears to be working differently on these two browsers compared to Chrome and IE11.

It is possible we're trying to use wrong frameworks, which were meant to target chiefly handheld device browsers?

Has anyone had luck adapting bootstrap to run with IE8? And if you gave up, what did you use instead?

Comment: Bootstrap should work both on desktop and mobile. And apparently they do support IE 8 and 9, though some things won't work: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9

Comment: You're confusing Bootstrap itself with some random theme that doesn't support ancient browsers.

Comment: And these frameworks are designed to target _modern_ browsers (< 10 years old); this has nothing to do with "handheld".

Comment: A lot of large companies (like ours) are still on these browsers, and they're not going anywhere, we checked out the "getting started" page, it helped only marginally. What can be used to be more browser-compatible instead, if bootstraps will have limited capacity to work on IEs?

Comment: Bootstrap goes out of their way to fully support ancient browsers.  But most other developers don't.  Microsoft does not support IE<11 at all, and most major websites (even most of Google) will not work on it.  You should upgrade your IEs.  (this is why compatibility mode exists)

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support